Function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,c) = - f(y,c)$ for all $x<c<y$
I looking to solve the following functional equation
$f(x,c) = - f(y,c)$ for all $x<c<y$
Clearly, the family  $f(x,c)=C  {\rm sign}(x-c)$ satisfies this property for every $C \in \mathbb{R}$.  My question is this the only solution?
I would like not to make any continuity or differentiability assumptions on $x$ if possible.

Well, any constant times that works.  What about something like $\sin(C\text {sign} (x-c))$?

@lulu sure. I mean up to a constant. Let me correct the question.

No reason to exclude $0$ as a solution.

I guess my $\sin $ example isn't very different.  What about $g(c)\times \text {sign} (x-c)$?

@lulu both are interesting. Thanks.

I think the $\sin$ example is redundant...since sign only takes two values, putting a function around it doesn't do much.  Once you multiply by $g(c)$ then things get interesting, of course.

First of all, note that the equation implies no constraint on $f(x,x)$. No constraints exist for the behavior of $f$ over points of the form $(x,x)$ for $x \in \Bbb R$. The below discussion concerns only what happens for $f(x,c)$ with $x \neq c$.
First, consider what occurs at a fixed $c$.
The condition implies that $f(x,c)$ is constant for $x \in (-\infty, c)$ and $x \in [c,\infty)$. That is, there exist constants $k_1, k_2$ such that $f(x,c)$ is $k_1$ for $x < c$ and $k_2$ for $x > c$. The condition further implies that $k_2 = -k_1$, so we can conclude that there is necessarily some $k \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x,c) = k\,\text{sgn}(x-c)$ for all $x$.
Since such a $k$ exists for EVERY $c \in \Bbb R$, we may think of that $k$ as the output of some function $g$. In other words, $f$ is necessarily of the form
$$
f(x,c) = g(c)\, \text{sgn}(x - c)
$$
for some function $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.
Moreover, it is easy to see that every $f$ of this form satisfies the necessary constraint.

Summarizing the result, we have the following characterization of functions $f$ satisfying your eqaution.
$f$ satisfies the constraint if and only if there exist functions $g,h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that
$$
f(x,c) = \begin{cases}
g(c) \,\text{sgn}(x - c) & x \neq c\\
h(x) & x = c
\end{cases}
$$
